# Datasheets as references in making device drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, freebsd, devices

Aside from FreeBSD or Linux operating systems' design structure and C programming knowledge, are datasheets enough as additional references in making device drivers?

Comment: If what you name "*datasheet*" is something like https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/io/io-controller-hub-10-family-datasheet.html , I mean includes a full "*functional desctiption*" then yes indeed. If it does not include a full functional description then no.

Comment: Yes @MC68020 similar to the document you've shared. Ah so, it depends...

Comment: Well : Understand that a driver will have to read / write devices registers / buffers with respect to timings / order sequence in order to perform some dedicated action. So how to write what where in order to perform the function needs to be precisely described. I you do not get such a description then, unless the device is claimed fully compliant with some standard (In which case it is very likely that the driver will have already been written) then you cannot expect succeeding in you project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not. A datasheet contains data about what the device can do.

For example, an airplane's datasheet would contain things like maximum speed, maximum safe altitude, maximum lift, expected transport capacity, kilogram of fuel per mile under some model flight assumptions … these kinds of things.

But: a plane's datasheet does not teach you how to fly a plane. It doesn't even tell you which direction to turn the sidestick to make the plane's nose go "up". That's not the job of a datasheet.

A programmer's manual, user guide, or similar documentation actually stating how to interact with the device would be necessary. Often, such documentation is not available, existing, incomplete, or wrong. Often, you discover "quirks" while working on the device, even when you have good documentation ("The manual says I need to program A, B and C before I can use the device to do D, but if I do not do A again directly after D, I can never do this a second time").

(and then we're at the point where you have a description of all knobs and levers in your specific cockpit. Still doesn't teach you how to fly a plane / write a good driver, but that's a different say, problem, and I think you addressed that with "design structure"; I think you're underselling the problem of knowing how a driver should look like, which is more than just knowing the kernel with which it interacts, but you have the general idea.)